# Issue in deploying ASP.NET MVC Application on the IIS Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

I am  trying to deploy a MVC Application on the IIS server.
I have shared the sqllocaldb using command prompt and created a Private LocalDB instance with name IIS_DB

I have also changed the connection string in my Web.Config file to

```
 <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\.\IIS_DB;Initial Catalog=aspnet-MvcApplication26-20141226150050;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-MvcApplication26-20141226150050.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

As of now I can view the Home Page when I click on Browse from the ISS Manager.

But when I click on the Register/Login  hyperlink, I get the following error

**Cannot attach the file 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MvcApplication26\App_Data\aspnet-MvcApplication26-20141226150050.mdf' as database 'aspnet-MvcApplication26-20141226150050'.**

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved this by manually copying the APP_Data folder from Visual Studio to the  my  application directory on the IIS server

Answer (score 0):

After sharing the database here is what you have to do
Go to visual studio => databaseexplorer => add connection
For the server name enter (LocalDb).\IIS_DB then right click on the connection and choose new query and execute this command:
create login [IIS APPPool\DefaultAPPPool] from windows;
exec sp_addsrvrolemember N'IIS APPPool\DefaultAPPPool, sysadmin

Comment: Already Done that I still get the same error

Cannot attach the file 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MvcApplication26\App_Data\aspnet-MvcApplication26-20141226150050.mdf' as database 'aspnet-MvcApplication26-20141226150050'.